# Entity Framework / SQL Multiple Shared Column Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have some tables which look like this:

#### Table A

```
[Id] IDENTITY INT NOT NULL
```

#### Table B

```
[Id] IDENTITY INT NOT NULL,
[TableAId] INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [FK_TableB_TableA] FOREIGN KEY [TableAId] REFERENCES [TableA]([Id])
```

#### Table C

```
[Id] IDENTITY INT NOT NULL,
[TableAId] INT NOT NULL,
[TableBId] INT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [FK_TableC_TableA] FOREIGN KEY [TableAId] REFERENCES [TableA]([Id])
```

Table B is only applicable to certain users however tables A and C are applicable to all. This means the foreign key `[FK_TableC_TableA]` is required.

What's the best way to ensure, at database level (or using entity framework) that when the reference to `TableB` from `TableC` is not null, `TableAId` in both `TableB` and `TableC` match?

Comment: By "Table **2**" do you mean "Table **B**" and "tables **1** and **3**" as in "tables **A** and **C**"?

Comment: Yup! Fixed, sorry it's been a long day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic use-case for *identifying relationships* and the resulting *natural* keys:

**Table B**

```
TableAId INT,
TableBNo INT,

PRIMARY KEY (TableAId, TableBNo),

FOREIGN KEY TableAId REFERENCES TableA (Id)
```

**Table C**

```
TableAId INT,
TableCNo INT,
TableBNo INT,

PRIMARY KEY (TableAId, TableCNo),

FOREIGN KEY TableAId REFERENCES TableA (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (TableAId, TableBNo) REFERENCES TableB (TableAId, TableBNo)
```

When `TableBNo` is non-NULL, the same **Table A** row must be references from both tables, simply because both foreign keys use the same field (`TableAId`).

The bottom foreign key is not enforced when `TableBNo` is NULL (since MS SQL Server implements [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx) foreign keys).